How do I get Windows Terminal to stop asking me every time I paste more than 5 KiB of text into the terminal?
Everytime I paste more than 5 KiB into Windows Terminal I get the following annoying messgae that's attempting to save me from myself.
I don't need it! How can I make it go away?
A very similar question has been asked before but it does not target the same warning message. Making the changes proposed there disables one warning, but not this one.


Take a look at the mentioned documentation in your linked post.
Set the property largePasteWarning as described at Paste warnings.

Well apparently I missed that, which makes this post look a bit stupid, but thank you for providing the answer. +1
